# Librecalc EXACT String Match Always Produces #NAME? Error

Tags: libreoffice-calc

When attempting to do an `EXACT` string match in Librecalc I always get a `#NAME?` error:

[image]

Moreover, Librecalc decapitalized the `'Buy'` that I entered to `'buy'`.  This is suspicious behavior that may be related.

Comment: What is in cell C61 (column C is chopped off in the image)?

Comment: in my opinion, unless you *really* need it to be case sensitive, then compare the values using `UPPER()`: `=EXACT(UPPER(C61),"BUY")`

Answer (score 0):

Your target string needs to be enclosed in double quotes rather than apostrophe's.  When using double quotes, you will also be able to specify the correct capitalization:

```
=EXACT(C61,"Buy")
```